# I want to opensource my code. Is it legal? Can I still publish?

Tags: publications, phd, software, open-science

I am a PhD (stipend) student at a [Max Planck Institute](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Max_Planck_Society) (for a biological science) here in Germany. I came here to write software, but ended up spending practically all my time doing wet-lab work. As a consequence, the programming I wanted to do had to be done in the evenings outside of the institute (although what constitutes 'PhD time' and 'programming time' is a bit of a blur, since I use my programs to solve PhD problems...)

Coming to the end of the PhD, I am now finally ready to "publish" the first of the three programs I have written during my time here in Germany, but there are three stakeholders all with competing interests in my software which make it difficult for me to know how to proceed...

**The Max Planck** - they will want to claim ownership of the software, because I wrote it while doing a PhD with them. Over the course of the PhD, no one from the Max Plank or the University have had any input whatsoever on the software, however, certainly between 10-20% of the code was developed 'on PhD time'.

**The Journals** - publishing is not a requirement, but it would be nice. It forms a stamp of approval (in some people's minds) and acts as free advertising at the very least. But for this to happen, I suppose I cannot "publish" my code already, meaning open source it and share it so people can bug-check it *before* publication?

**The Users** - Arguably the most important stakeholder for me, because I wrote this software for them. I want to make the code's licence as permissive as legally possible, probably under Creative Commons Zero to aid with this, but I feel this will make publishing impossible, and it may not even be allowed if I am not the owner of the copyright in the first place.

How should I proceed?

Comment: Please can you remove all the distracting stuff from the question, and simply tell us what your contract with Max Planck says?

Comment: I cannot read German so I do not know - that why i specified Max Plank and Stipend so maybe someone else knows.

Comment: @user3329564: Are you serious about that? You have signed a contract without knowing what is stated in there?

Comment: You have obviously never done a PhD in Germany. I was given about 30 contracts to sign, no translation help, and to hire a translator cost €30 an hour. They wanted a week to translate it all, and the MPI gave me a weekend to return the forms else I couldnt be enrolled on the PhD. This is incredibly common in Germany. Probably everywhere else too..

Comment: In general your employer owns al the IP concerning the work you do while at work, or at home if working for them or with equipment provided by them, unless stated otherwise in your contract.

Comment: *I suppose I cannot "publish" my code already, meaning open source it and share it so people can bug-check it before publication?* Yes you can. In fact, you have to. Typically you need to show active user interest before you can publish your software formally (e.g. github stars, download, mentions on twitter, ...). See for instance [JMLR MLOSS guidelines](http://jmlr.org/mloss/mloss-info.html), which state "*Evidence of an active user community should be demonstrated ...*".

Comment: Speak to your advisor, or your local bioinformatics team. I'd guess rather than MPI trying to wrench your code + IP from you and commercialise it, they'll be pretty uninterested and let you publish under whatever license you want.

Comment: @MarcClaesen  - oh wow! That is totally new information to me - I would have thought having an active community around the software constituted 'prior publication in the public domain' and would have barred it from any journal. This essentially answers the 'heart' of one of the issues this question addresses - could you make it an answer? :)

Comment: @MarcClaesen This is totally not the case in life sciences, indeed may be very specific to your field. No comparable evidence is needed for PLOS comp. biol., Bioinformatics etc.

Comment: @blmoore - I highly doubt it too. But as we've seen from signing contracts I could not read, I dont want to end up in a difficult situation in the future because I was told "everything will probably be ok" in the past. The MPI has a track record of being ruthless with money, particularly when that money can be extracted from PhD students.

Comment: @user3329564 publications are not patents. Just because software is already available, doesn't mean you can't still publish a paper about it. Fortunately, it really doesn't work that way.

Comment: Note: Creative Commons [recommends against using Creative Commons licenses for software](https://wiki.creativecommons.org/wiki/Frequently_Asked_Questions#Can_I_apply_a_Creative_Commons_license_to_software.3F).

Comment: Yeah, i was actually recommended elsewhere to go for the WTFPL (https://tldrlegal.com/licenses/tags/Public%20Domain) but the name is the only thing holding me back. How could I tell a visiting emeritus professor  'I released my code under WTFPL' without expecting them to take a big sigh and mumbling 'god damn millennials... '

Comment: @user3329564: It is extremely uncommon in Germany to sign a work contract without understanding it (and at least in a privately owned organisation, it is totally irresponsible because you will most probably be scammed in some way). Even as a native German speaker, my work contracts at German universities so far were always explained to me by the university's HR department step by step to make sure I really know and understand every single detail written in there.

Comment: "I was given about 30 contracts to sign, no translation help, and to hire a translator cost €30 an hour. They wanted a week to translate it all, and the MPI gave me a weekend to return the forms else I couldnt be enrolled on the PhD." This is incredibly irresponsible. You should discuss this with your PhDNet representative and make sure it doesn't happen to others.

Comment: I did and they were *really* supportive - they helped me understand the difference between an MPI stipend and a contract, got me a 10% bonus on my stipend, helped me get proper health insurance... I literally don't want to know what kind of state id be in if it wasn't for PhDNet. I never asked about IP because i didnt have anything back then, but now perhaps I should find out...

Comment: @user3329564 Only "they" (your Max Planck Institute) will be able to tell you in detail. Having said that, IF you were on a DFG grant or some EU grant, there may be a stipulation that the code has to be openly accessible - so you may want to research the conditions of your grant. (E.g. in the UK EPSRC requires that work is published in a way that makes it openly accessible.)
However your research institution may very well still have a claim on the copyright as well as have a say on the license under which the code is released and only they can help you with that.

Comment: Even if you didn't understand the contract at the time, I hope you kept your copy and can translate them now.

Comment: @JoErNanO "In general your employer ..." - I don't know how it works in Germany, but in the UK a PhD student is not an employee (except for possible part-time employment for supervisions etc).

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I'm the main developer of several open-source libraries, one published and one under review, so I can give you a pretty up-to-date overview on open-source in the machine learning community. This may differ for your field, but probably not much.

Whether or not your university will allow you to open-source and/or publish depends entirely on them. Based on my experience, open-sourcing can be sensitive depending on how old-fashioned your university/lab is. However, *if* they are fine with open-sourcing, they will certainly be OK with publishing too (after all, it's a free paper!). Only way to know is to ask your advisor.

The only move you have here is to ask your advisor. To my knowledge, at least some MPIs are very much in favor of open-source (e.g. Bernhard Schölkopf, head of MPI intelligent systems, is a co-author of [an important open-source mission statement within machine learning](http://kyb.tuebingen.mpg.de/fileadmin/user_upload/files/publications/attachments/JMLR-8-Sonnenburg_4768%5b0%5d.pdf)).

## Releasing software before publication

> I suppose I cannot "publish" my code already, meaning open source it and share it so people can bug-check it before publication?

Yes you can and in fact you should. Typically you need to show active user interest before you can publish your software formally (e.g. github stars, download, mentions on twitter, ...). See for instance [JMLR MLOSS guidelines](http://jmlr.org/mloss/mloss-info.html), which state "*Evidence of an active user community should be demonstrated ...*".

In any case, releasing software prior to submitting your paper is not a problem. Publications don't work like patents.

## Publication venues

Lately, there is a lot of journal interest in software. To name a few:

- [JMLR MLOSS](http://jmlr.org/mloss/)
- [Plos Computational Biology: Software](http://www.ploscollections.org/article/browseIssue.action?issue=info:doi/10.1371/issue.pcol.v03.i10)
- [The R Journal](http://journal.r-project.org/)
- [Journal of Statistical Software](http://www.jstatsoft.org/)

A more complete list is available at http://www.software.ac.uk/resources/guides/which-journals-should-i-publish-my-software

Next to journals, you have a lot of conferences/workshops specifically about software. For many projects, you are actually better off publishing there with the added benefit of shorter review times and far less drama.

### License

> I want to make the code's licence as  permissive as legally possible, probably under Creative Commons Zero to aid  with this ...

Creative Commons licenses aren't really suitable for software. Be aware that choosing an open-source license isn't entirely trivial, that is open-source licenses don't necessarily allow users to do whatever they want. Most commonly used permissive licenses include [BSD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BSD_licenses), [MIT](http://opensource.org/licenses/MIT), [Apache](http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0) and [WTF](http://www.wtfpl.net/) licenses as opposed to the [GPL](http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-3.0.en.html). I do recommend informing yourself about the main differences of highly permissive licenses vis-a-vis GPL-style licenses. Some questions you should ask yourself include

- Do you want your license to permit commercial use within closed-source projects for free? If not, slap a GPL on it and (optionally) dual license your software.
- Do you want to permit non-GPL open-source software to build upon your work? If so, then make sure your license isn't GPL (this is because of the [copyleft](http://www.gnu.org/copyleft/copyleft.html) nature of the GPL).

In my opinion, the best license types for relatively small (but useful) research software projects are usually highly permissive (BSD, Apache, ...). Your university's technology transfer office may disagree, if you even have to go through them (if MPI claims IP ownership of the software you developed you have to pass through the TTO).

Comment: The link to software publishing journals is great!

Comment: \*Sigh\* Once again, with feeling: **GPL does *not* stop anyone from using your software commercially.** It doesn't even stop anyone from modifying copies of your software as long as *if they publish it in any form they also publish the source code*.

Comment: "MPI is generally in favor of open-source": there are many MPIs, and they are more-or-less independent. A statement from the MPG (Max Planck Society) would be relevant, but the opinion of an individual research at a different MPI is not really indicative of the whole situation.

Comment: @l0b0 while I agree that my blanket statement should be modified (which I will do later), it must be noted that in many cases the GPL effectively prevents incorporation of a given module in larger commercial projects. Software that is sold in its own right is typically closed-source. Point remains that GPL significantly restricts use cases, and was originally aimed at preventing inclusion in any closed-source system (which was the key characteristic of commercial software at the time of origin of the GPL).

Comment: @Max thanks for the info, I didn't know about that!

Comment: @l0b0 "You must license the entire work, as a whole, under this License to anyone who comes into possession of a copy. This License will therefore apply, along with any applicable section 7 additional terms, to the whole of the work, and all its parts, regardless of how they are packaged. This License gives no permission to license the work in any other way, but it does not invalidate such permission if you have separately received it." - This seems to contradict your claim regarding publication.

Comment: Cc0 is absolutely acceptable for software.  There are other cc licenses that are not, but cc0 is similar to unlicense, wtfpl, bsd 0-clause or public domain dedication

Comment: CC0 can be problematic for software, as for that matter can Unlicence and PD dedication, due to the vagaries of public domain law by jurisdiction. BSD is typically safer, for software that will be used worldwide.

Comment: @Taemyr Yes, by "publish the source code" I meant implicitly "under the GPL". Sorry, legalese is not my forte :)

Answer (score 12):

**The Journals:** Generally, open sourcing a code should not be an obstacle for publication. To the contrary: there is a movement to make as much academic code as possible open - see for example [GitXiv](http://gitxiv.com). The only problem I see is that open sourcing the code prior to publication may impact the anonymity of blind review. I have however read and authored multiple CS papers where the code was open before publication and nobody complained. Sometimes it was kind of ridiculous - we wrote a paper reporting on an already released new version of a relatively known tool that our group develops for almost ten years, but with anonymized authors :-)

You may want to ask editorial board of the journal on their policy on open code and possible delay opening the code past publication.

**Max Planck:** Have you asked the institute on their opinion? Or is there a precedent where they refused to open source a code they developed? In my field, having other groups use your software is a bonus and thus the university supports open sourcing code.

**EDIT:** If the institute opposes open sourcing the code, you may still argue that the code is not owned by them. It depends whether you worked for them (had an employment contract) or if it was "school work". If you had an employment contract, open sourcing would probably be on the darker side of gray area, as at least part of the software was developed "on the clock".

Answer (score 4):

I was recently interested in this issue as well. Although I'm not a lawyer, there are 2 interesting paragraphs in the German law which are relevant.

Copyright law 69b (http://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/urhg/BJNR012730965.html)

*§ 69b Urheber in Arbeits- und Dienstverhältnissen
(1) Wird ein Computerprogramm von einem Arbeitnehmer in Wahrnehmung seiner Aufgaben oder nach den Anweisungen seines Arbeitgebers geschaffen, so ist ausschließlich der Arbeitgeber zur Ausübung aller vermögensrechtlichen Befugnisse an dem Computerprogramm berechtigt, sofern nichts anderes vereinbart ist.
(2) Absatz 1 ist auf Dienstverhältnisse entsprechend anzuwenden.*

In my interpretation this essentially boils done to, although you retain the copyright, your employer has the exclusive right to do everything with the software you wrote (including prohibiting it from open source distribution), unless the employer explicitly refrains from this right.

That being said, there is another paragraph in the German constitution which is possibly in conflict:

German constitution Paragraph 5 (http://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/gg/BJNR000010949.html)

*(1) Jeder hat das Recht, seine Meinung in Wort, Schrift und Bild frei zu äußern und zu verbreiten und sich aus allgemein zugänglichen Quellen ungehindert zu unterrichten. Die Pressefreiheit und die Freiheit der Berichterstattung durch Rundfunk und Film werden gewährleistet. Eine Zensur findet nicht statt.
(2) Diese Rechte finden ihre Schranken in den Vorschriften der allgemeinen Gesetze, den gesetzlichen Bestimmungen zum Schutze der Jugend und in dem Recht der persönlichen Ehre.
(3) Kunst und Wissenschaft, Forschung und Lehre sind frei. Die Freiheit der Lehre entbindet nicht von der Treue zur Verfassung.*

Part (3) garantees that work produced in science (of course this includes the software written in the framework of a phd thesis) may be distributed freely and may not be censored.

In a nutshell, the law seems not to be entirely clear on this (although I guess that the constitution takes precedence), and your best bet is to discuss the possibility of opensourcing you software with your employer.

Comment: I don't know about Germany, but in the UK a PhD student is not an employee, so there is no employer to have exclusive rights.

Answer (score 0):

Whatever the legal situation, you *must* talk to your advisor and the people at MPI about what you want to do. If nothing else, just out of common courtesy. Getting into some squabble or even legal trouble with them is definiteley not in your best interest.